# Simple HTML page not able to make responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I've build a webpage currently only with the header in it with simple `html` and `css`. And I've made sure that I've only used the `px` unit to specify the root font size and the rest to use `rem` unit, yet the page is not responsive. When the windows is scaled down the fonts are staying the same.

CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 10px;
}

body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif; 
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.7;
  color: #777;
  padding: 3rem;
}

.text-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(
    -50%,
    -50%
  ); 
  text-align: center;
}

.header {
  height: 95vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
      to right bottom,
      rgba(126, 213, 111, 0.8),
      rgba(40, 180, 133, 0.8)
    ),
    url(../img/hero.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top;
  clip-path: polygon(
    0 0,
    100% 0,
    100% 75vh,
    0 100%
  ); 
  position: relative;
}

.logo-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4rem;
  left: 4rem;
}

.logo {
  height: 3.5rem;
}

.text-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.heading-primary {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 6rem;
}

.heading-primary-main {
  display: block;
  font-size: 6rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 3.5rem;
  animation-name: moveInLeft;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
}

.heading-primary-sub {
  display: block;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 1.75rem;
  animation: moveInRight 1s ease-in;

}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/icon-font.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <!-- tab icon -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="img/favicon.png" />

    <title>Natours | Exciting tours for adventurous people</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="header">
      <div class="logo-box">
        <img class="logo" src="img/logo-white.png" alt="logo" />
      </div>
      <div class="text-box">
        <h1 class="heading-primary">
          <span class="heading-primary-main">Outdoors</span>
          <span class="heading-primary-sub">is where life happends</span>
        </h1>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-white btn-animated">Discover out tours</a>
      </div>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

Anybody see where I screwed up?
Browser: Chrome

Answer (score 0):

Change font-size to units of vw instead of rem.

```
 .heading-primary-main {
        display: block;
        font-size: 10vw;
        font-weight: 400;
        letter-spacing: 1.0rem;
        animation-name: moveInLeft;
        animation-duration: 1s;
        animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }

    .heading-primary-sub {
        display: block;
        font-size: 4vw;
        font-weight: 700;
        letter-spacing: .75rem;
        animation: moveInRight 1s ease-in;

    }
```

You will have to play with your letter spacing to get it to your liking.

Answer (score -3):

I would recommend calling the font from the CSS so you only use it when you need it.

Another recommendation would be that you use endpoints in css and when you want to change the font use the !important

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries